# wireless mouse prevents boot up

Tags: usb, mouse

My new Microsoft wireless USB mouse prevents my computer from booting up.  If I unplug the USB mouse receiver, when the computer is off, the computer will boot normally.  After the computer boots up and I plug in the mouse, it works fine.  I installed the latest mouse software for my Vista system,... no difference.

Comment: What do you mean prevents boot up? Is there an error message of some sort or it just doesn't boot into your OS?

Answer (score 0):

Is boot from USB set as an option in the BIOS?  Try disabling that in the boot order.

I have also seen a couple of systems that hang on boot when certain USB devices are plugged in even if USB is removed from boot order. System would show a black screen with blinking cursor and would sometimes boot after a long  period of time. Never found a solution.